# R: formula with piping

Tags: r

I have an R formula that uses the piping operator %T>% in the magrittr package. However, I am unable to figure out exactly what it does. Would anyone be able to tell me what this formula does and how I can write it without the piping operator.

```
dataframe %T>% {variable_name <<- .[condition,sum(another variable)]}
```

Here, condition is something like

```
size > 100
```

and another variable is something like

```
length
```

Both size and length are variables in the dataframe.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Comment: You should mention how/in which package this operator is defined. In fact, you should share a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @jim, try reading the help file (type `help("%T>%")`).  Then say what you still don't understand.  What do `condition` and `another variable` etc. represent?  It's in the `magrittr` package by the way.

Comment: I understand the whole piping thing (at least the concept). I just don't know how it works in this example. Especially with the { } and the fact that the RHS is not a function.

Comment: Is your `dataframe` actually a `data.table`? The `sum(another var)` doesn't seem to make much sense in the context of a `data.frame`.

Comment: Assuming it is data.table, would you be able to tell me what it is trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

`%T>%`  is the "tee" operator. As defined in [`magrittr`'s vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html):

> `%T>%` works like `%>%`, except it returns the left-hand side value, and not the result of the right-hand side operation.

In other words when you use the tee operator :

1. The operation after the tee is done
2. The pipe "restarts"  from before the tee, and skip to function after the tee.

Tees can be combined.

Combined with `{..}`, it can be used to do more than one thing, eg a `ggplot2` graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% 
    filter(Sepal.Length > 5.2) %T>% 
    {print(ggplot(data=., aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) + geom_point())}  %>% 
    head
```

Which prints the first lines on the filtered `iris` *and* produces a `ggplot2` as a side effect. The latter needs to be printed to be produced in such case.

You can see the tee operator as a way to avoid dead end: for instance a `ggplot2` returns a `gg`/`ggplot`object, but that may not be the thing you would like to continue the pipe with. Typically, you may want to produce a graph at some point within the pipe, then continue the pipe.

Comment: So in my example, would I be able to write it as dataframe${variable_name <<- .[size<100,sum(length)]}

Comment: I think the first step would be to avoid `<<-`. Can you express in a non pipe way what you want to do ?

Comment: Well the formula that I provided is what I am looking at. I am trying to express it in a non pipe way

Comment: :). could you explain it with sentences then ?

Comment: That's the thing I am trying to ask. I am not sure what it is trying to do, which is why I thought posting it on here would give me some ideas.

Comment: Well, I guess you can still replace it with: `dataframe[condition,sum(another variable)]` and see what it returns. But `sum` to index a df column is quite unorthodox.

Comment: what about the new variable? how do i incorporate that somehow?

Comment: I'd avoid using `<<-`. So you can keep the filtering above and set the result of it to a new variable using `<-` or `->`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `dataframe` in your original expression is a `data.table`, what you are doing is: subsetting your `dataframe` with `condition`, calculating the sum of the `other variable` in the subset, assigning the sum to a global variable called `variable_name` and printing the contents of `dataframe`.

Vincent Bonhomme already explained what the "tee" operator does. That is, it makes your expression return the value of `dataframe` in this case. I think the confusion here is caused by the `.` in the expression. From `help("%>%")`:

> **Placing lhs elsewhere in rhs call**
>
> Often you will want lhs to the rhs call at another position than the
>   first. For this purpose you can use the dot (.) as placeholder. For
>   example, y %>% f(x, .) is equivalent to f(x, y) and z %>% f(x, y, arg
>   = .) is equivalent to f(x, y, arg = z).

Here's an example of the expression in your post:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 5:1)

# original expression
dt %T>% {z1 <<- .[x > 2, sum(y)]}
#        x y
#     1: 1 5
#     2: 2 4
#     3: 3 3
#     4: 4 2
#     5: 5 1

z1
#    [1] 6

# equivalently
z2 <- dt[x > 2, sum(y)]; dt
#        x y
#     1: 1 5
#     2: 2 4
#     3: 3 3
#     4: 4 2
#     5: 5 1

# more verbosely
z3 <- sum(subset(dt, x > 2)$y); dt
#        x y
#     1: 1 5
#     2: 2 4
#     3: 3 3
#     4: 4 2
#     5: 5 1

all.equal(z1, z2, z3)
#    [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What does the "; dt" in the second expression do?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It just prints `dt` to the console. That's just to replicate what happens when you use the "tee" pipe instead of the regular pipe operator.

Comment: it just prints `dt` on the same line as the previous command.